# String.getBytes("UTF-32") returns different results on JVM and Dalvik VM

Tags: java, android, string, jvm, dalvik

I have a 48 character `AES-192` encryption key which I'm using to decrypt an encrypted database.

However, it tells me the key length is invalid, so I logged the results of getBytes().

When I execute:

```
final String string = "346a23652a46392b4d73257c67317e352e3372482177652c";
final byte[] utf32Bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-32");
System.out.println(utf32Bytes.length);
```

Using BlueJ on my mac (Java Virtual Machine), I get `192` as the output.

However, when I use:

```
Log.d(C.TAG, "Key Length: " + String.valueOf("346a23652a46392b4d73257c67317e352e3372482177652c".getBytes("UTF-32").length));
```

I get `196` as the output.

Does anybody know why this is happening, and where Dalvik is getting an additional 4 bytes from?

Comment: Why not dump the bytes to see?

Comment: @JonSkeet Good idea. I'll edit in a bit.

Comment: it's probably the BOM, 00 00 FE FF

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should specify endianess on both machines

```
final byte[] utf32Bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-32BE");
```

Note that `"UTF-32BE"` is a different encoding, not special `.getBytes` parameter. It has fixed endianess and doesn't need BOM. More info: http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#gen6

Comment: Why would that affect the *number* of bytes ?

Comment: Because endianess specified UTF32 doesn't need BOM. Worth a shot.

Comment: Ah yes. This was the problem. They both show 192 now. I'll accept when the system lets me.

Comment: @RaghavSood Or instead of using 192 bytes you could use just 24. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Why would you UTF-32 encode plain a hexidecimal number. Thats 8x larger than it needs to be. :P

```
String s = "346a23652a46392b4d73257c67317e352e3372482177652c";
byte[] bytes = new BigInteger(s, 16).toByteArray();
String s2 = new BigInteger(1, bytes).toString(16);
System.out.println("Strings match is "+s.equals(s2)+" length "+bytes.length);
```

prints

```
Strings match is true length 24
```

Comment: While this works better with the task I'm doing, @Esailija's answer is more accurate to this question. Thanks for this as well!